# Populate form input field with php variable value

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have an html form and I need to populate one of the input fields with the url of the page the form is on. To get the url I have:

```
<?php $pageURL="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];?>
```

To populate the input field I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[   
$(document).ready(function(){
    var getLabel = $(".monkForm label:contains('Page URL')");
    var getFor = getLabel.attr('for');
    var splitFor = getFor.split('_');
    var inputID = $("#" + getFor );
    var wrapID = $("#w" + splitFor[1] );
    wrapID.hide();
    inputID.val('<?=$pageURL;?>');
});
// ]]> 
</script>
```

The input field label on the form is "Page URL". The problem is that the page URL is not being added to the input field.

Comment: don't use the php function, simply use `window.location.href` to grab the url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use PHP as it is server side. Get the URL using Javascript instead:

```
inputID.val(window.location.href);
```

Answer (score 1):

you rather than use:

```
inputID.val(window.location.href);
```

don't use php statment.